# How to access Listbox from another Thread UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to log into a listbox in uwp from another thread.

I know from windows forms that i should use delegates. But their are no invoke methods. This is my interface i use for logging. And that was the first thing i tried to use.

```
public interface ILoggingService
{
    void LogInformation(LogEntryType logEntryType,string logEntryMessage);
}



delegate void LoggerDelegate(LogEntryType logEntryType,string message);
LoggerDelegate _loggerDelegate = new LoggerDelegate(LogInformation);

public void LogInformation(LogEntryType logEntryType,string logEntryMessage)
    {
        if (lbxInformation.InvokeRequired)
        {
           lbxRequestInformation.Invoke(logRequestInformationDelegate,message);
        }
        else
        {
            lbxInformation.Items.Add(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dispatcher.RunAsync to update the UI from another thread. Here is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/using-windows-runtime-objects-in-a-multithreaded-environment